# Blank page deploying angular 8 app in firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

i don't understand why, my angular web app works perfectly in local but when i deploy it to firebase hosting it only shows me a blank page.
In my root folder of the app in the console i write:

```
ng build --prod
```

And it creates a carpet called "dist" and inside dist another called myproject with all the files in it

Now, in the terminal i execute

```
firebase init
```

Then, i select **Hosting** and **Database** and then my project in firebase and then it asks me **what file of database rules i want to use** i let the **default** and then **What i want to use as public directory** and i write **dist/myproject** bc the files are inside myproject folder inside dist as i said earlier.

Then, as it is an angular app, when it asks me **Do you want to configure as single-page app** i say **yes** (i tried whit no and it doesn't work either).

Finally, when it ask **do you want to overwrite the index.html** i say **no** and it finishes.

The firebase.json looks like this:

```
{
"hosting": {
    "public": "dist/myproject",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Finally i do

```
firebase deploy
```

And happen what i say, it deploy "successfully" my app but when i enter it's only a white page. I don't know what it could be, can anyone help me?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I've hosted a few Angular SPAs on Firebase Hosting and you just need to do what's called "Ahead-of-Time" compilation to make it work.  But first check:

1. Are there are any error messages in your browser's console?
2. When you view the page source is it blank or is your app's index.html there?

If you answered "No" and "Yes" try compiling with AOT and redeploying:
`ng build --prod --aot`

Comment: You're right, when i compile it with tha --aot flag it shows me a strange error, that's why it didn't work! But i still don't understand the error, it says this:

node_modules/@angular/fire/angularfire2.d.ts:50:96 - error TS2344: Type 'T[K]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.

Comment: I solved it adding _"skipLibCheck": true_ in the tsconfig.json and it compiled but the web still in blank and it shows this error:  

_TypeError: sg(...).auth is not a function_

Comment: That's a different problem, please mark this as solved since it resolved the first issue.  For the second error you'd need to post your code because it's most likely you're missing a provider or declaration file.

Answer (score 0):

for me, it worked after I changed

```
"hosting": {
    "public": "dist/project-name"}
```

in firebase.json. The point it to also add the project name folder after the build folder, which is "dist" in my case.